# "Either though" meaning

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, vocabulary

I know the meaning of the words either and tho separately but I'm not sure about the combination of them...Could you please tell me the meaning of "either though" by giving some examples?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you could give us an example of where you've run into this string of words.

Comment: @snailboat I said someone I wanted them to be happy and keep smiling and they said,"You either tho"

Comment: I don't understand "You either though".  Could you have misheard?

Comment: So this was the conversation: "Stay happy and keep smiling." "You either though."? That response doesn't really make sense. I'd assume it was an attempt at extending "me neither", which means "that also does not apply to me", *e.g.* "I'm never happy or smiling." "Me neither". Was it a native speaker you were talking to?

Comment: As an spanish speaker, it makes sense to me, I would translate it as: "Mantente feliz y sonriendo", "tu también". I have heard that expresion several times but what I don't understand is why adding the "though" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I can't produce an example that may contain the questioned string of words unless they are separated by comma:

> I can't find it either, though it might be right before my eyes.

This said, the two words can't go together so as to make a viable construction.

Comment: It sounds like they're referring to spoken words, so I think you can assume a comma was present if you like. I'm confused by "the two words can't go together so as to make a viable construction" immediately after showing us a way the words can go together to make a viable construction.

Comment: @DCShannon In Lucian Sava's example, the two words are certainly linearly adjacent, but they don't appear to be in construction with one another.

Comment: @snailboat Maybe that's what was meant. I'm looking at the whole sentence as the construction.